# Draw exponential plot with confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, exponential

I have four cell samples which expand exponentially, each starting from a different timepoint. I'm new to R, but am trying to plot their exponential curves, with 95% confidence interval shaded area, to see whether they match up and cross over. I believe I should be using ggplot, but can't get it to display the data. I'd be grateful for help.

I've managed this so far:

```
ggplot(series, aes(series$day, series$`118Q`)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(data = series, aes(x = series$day, y = series$`118Q`)) + 
  geom_path() + 
  xlim(2000, 3000) +
  ylim(0, 200)
```

My data:

```
day,29Q,71Q,97Q,118Q
3,30.42333333,,,
7,,,,
10,30.49333333,,,
14,,,,
18,30.48666667,,,
21,,,,
25,30.48666667,,,
28,,,,
35,30.47333333,,,
38,30.47333333,,,
41,,,,
44,30.45666667,,,
3,30.37333333,,,
7,,,,
10,30.44333333,,,
14,,,,
18,30.43666667,,,
21,,,,
25,30.43666667,,,
28,,,,
35,30.42333333,,,
38,30.42333333,,,
41,,,,
44,30.40666667,,,
3,30.37333333,,,
7,,,,
10,30.44333333,,,
14,,,,
18,30.43666667,,,
21,,,,
25,30.43666667,,,
28,,,,
35,30.42333333,,,
38,30.42333333,,,
41,,,,
44,30.40666667,,,
1303,,69.42333333,,
1307,,,,
1310,,69.46666667,,
1314,,,,
1318,,69.51,,
1321,,,,
1325,,69.47666667,,
1328,,,,
1335,,69.47,,
1338,,69.44666667,,
1341,,,,
1344,,69.44333333,,
1303,,68.42333333,,
1307,,,,
1310,,68.46666667,,
1314,,,,
1318,,68.51,,
1321,,,,
1325,,68.47666667,,
1328,,,,
1335,,68.47,,
1338,,68.44666667,,
1341,,,,
1344,,68.44333333,,
1303,,69.52333333,,
1307,,,,
1310,,69.56666667,,
1314,,,,
1318,,69.61,,
1321,,,,
1325,,69.57666667,,
1328,,,,
1335,,69.57,,
1338,,69.54666667,,
1341,,,,
1344,,69.54333333,,
1841,,,,
1845,,,97.6866667,
1848,,,,
1852,,,97.6866667,
1856,,,,
1859,,,98.5666667,
1863,,,,
1866,,,98.5766667,
1873,,,,
1876,,,,
1879,,,99.39,
1882,,,,
1841,,,,
1845,,,97.4966667,
1848,,,,
1852,,,97.6633333,
1856,,,,
1859,,,98.6633333,
1863,,,,
1866,,,98.69,
1873,,,98.69,
1876,,,,
1879,,,99.6533333,
1882,,,,
1841,,,,
1845,,,97.5916667,
1848,,,,
1852,,,97.675,
1856,,,,
1859,,,98.615,
1863,,,,
1866,,,98.63333335,
1873,,,98.69,
1876,,,,
1879,,,99.52166665,
1882,,,,
2143,,,,117.8233333
2147,,,,
2150,,,,118.7833333
2154,,,,
2158,,,,118.7333333
2161,,,,
2165,,,,
2168,,,,
2175,,,,120.5566667
2178,,,,
2181,,,,
2184,,,,121.48
2143,,,,117.8233333
2147,,,,
2150,,,,118.7833333
2154,,,,
2158,,,,118.7333333
2161,,,,
2165,,,,
2168,,,,
2175,,,,120.5566667
2178,,,,
2181,,,,
2184,,,,121.51
2143,,,,117.8233333
2147,,,,
2150,,,,118.1922222
2154,,,,
2158,,,,118.8983333
2161,,,,
2165,,,,
2168,,,,
2175,,,,120.5055556
2178,,,,
2181,,,,
2184,,,,121.60125
```

I'd like to achieve something like this, though with the exponential lines for each sample projected forwards and back over the whole graph:

[image]

Comment: Please include he data in the question rather than a link. Don't use `$` in the `aes`

Comment: Thank you, I've uploaded my data

Comment: you can use `nlme::nls` to fit an exponential curve - but it won't easily give you confidence intervals